# is it a bad idea to use goto statements in guess the number game ? C#

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to programming. I've heard that using GOTO statements is not good. so i would appreciate any recommendations on what to use instead.Thanks for helping.

```
    Start:
        Random numGen = new Random();
        int num = numGen.Next(1, 101);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
        Console.Write("Your answer: ");
    fail:
        int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (answer == num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations,the number was " + num);
            Console.WriteLine();
            goto Start;
        }

        else if (answer > num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lower");
            goto fail;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Higher");
            goto fail;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, why you don't use methods?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might suit this question better

Comment: it's always a bad idea, there are so many better ways to organize your code

Comment: Goto is always a bad idea

Comment: Your question is opinion based and off-topic. I'd start by reading up on what the goto statement does so you can make your own mind up on its usage

Comment: There is no problem to experiment with `goto`. The alternative with `while(true)` loop below are not better in readability or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that Gotos are "always" a bad idea but wherever possible try to avoid them.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
var random = new Random();
while (true)
{
    var number = random.Next(1, 101);
    Console.WriteLine("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
    Console.Write("Your answer: ");
    int answer;
    while ((answer= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())) != number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(answer > number ? "Lower" : "Higher");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations,the number was " + number);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite this, for example, to use a loop:

```
Random numGen = new Random();
int num = numGen.Next(1, 101);
Console.WriteLine("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
Console.Write("Your answer: ");

while(true) 
{
    int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (answer == num)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (answer > num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Lower");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Higher");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Congratulations,the number was " + num);
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Thanks For your Help !

Comment: Though while(true) also makes the code unneccessarily difficult to read, because you have to find all the breaks within the loop. Better the use the while to define the condition.

Comment: @JanErikGunnar I thought about that too but I couldn't really figure out a way without code repetition.

Comment: I made a change to the answer but the edit has not been accepted by peer review... Here is a suggestion: https://pastebin.com/UDgTeZCw

Comment: Thought of that, but I don't like the "if( .. > .. ) else if ( .. < .. )" a lot either.

Comment: Why not? It's perfectly valid and easy to read. Searching through a block of code looking for "breaks" is not